# angularjs - datepicker popup opens both in start date and end date

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

How can I prevent the datepicker popup from opening at the same time when I click on only 1 input?

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/byx6Za1lOH2Q8cYX4lgy?p=preview)

```
<form>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="fromDate">From:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" show-weeks="false" ng-click="open($event)" name="fromDate" id="fromDate" />
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)">
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
            </button>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="toDate">To:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="toDate" is-open="opened2" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" show-weeks="false" ng-click="open($event)" name="toDate" id="toDate" />
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)">
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
            </button>
          </span>
        </div>
      </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at your plunkr. In your script.js file you have the following

```
$scope.open = function($event) {
  $event.preventDefault();
  $event.stopPropagation();

  $scope.opened = true;
   $scope.opened2 = true;
};
```

$scope.opened = true; and $scope.opened2=true; are both being set. This is forcing both of them to open. You are calling this function when either of the calendar buttons is clicked

```
ng-click="open($event)"
```

is-open will force the calendar to show when the variable is set somewhere else in code as well. Remember it is **2-way binding**

As for your solution. A simple way I can think to fix it is to pass another variable into your open method telling it which button was clicked so

```
$scope.open = function($event, calId) {
  $event.preventDefault();
  $event.stopPropagation();

  if(calId===1) $scope.opened = true;
  if(calId===2) $scope.opened2 = true;
};
```

Then in your html for the buttons change to the following passing in a 1,2,3 etc.. for whichever datepicker on the page you want to display.

```
ng-click="open($event,1)"
```